# MVC Controller Called twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Product controller with Index action, which basically creates the view form for post and Index (Post action verb) action on the ProductController which basically save the product to db but when validation errors occur, I am returning a View(mymodel) else when saved, I am returning RedirectToAction("Created,"Product") but for some odd reason when I break into the code , it is hitting the Product Controller action twice rather than just once. Hence the product has 2 records instead of one.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View()
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection fc)
{
    // 2 calls are made to this controller
    try
    {
        // save the product
        return RedirectToAction("Created"); 
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // recreate the model from form collection
        return View(viewData); // when a validation error occurs it comes into the catch block 
    }
}
```

Comment: You should fix your naming - controller!=action. I can't edit yours post myself yet. :/

Comment: You don't need 2 Index actions, if they differ by 1 nullable parameter.

Comment: Instead of passing FormCollection, try binding: "public ActionResult Save(Product product){...}".

Comment: I didnt understand by what you meant controller!=action ? Where am I going wrong ..can you pls comment

Comment: Product - controller; 
Index - action of controller; 
Index.aspx - view. 
This seems incorrect to me: "return Index(null); //this controller called intially".

Comment: Anyway - can't find any reason why that action gets called twice. I'm blind/dumb or some more info should be provided.

Comment: You need to post the html form that posts to that controller action(Save). This might show us why it's getting posted twice.

Comment: Do you use an IoC container? If so, just check the default lifetime of your controller.

Comment: I have changed my code as per comments and have just one Index action and one Index action with POST verb, but the Index with Post verb is getting called twice.No Iocs used

Comment: You still need to show us the HTML form that posts to that Index action.  There could be an error there that is making it post twice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sometimes I have found Firebug to cause this behavior. Try disabling its [*Script* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel), if you have it installed.

Explanation: In some cases Firebug isn't able to get the script sources for the display within its Script panel. In these cases it initiates a second request to get them. See [issue 7401](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7401) for some discussion about this, which alleviates the problem and is fixed with Firebug 2.0.2.

Comment: This has been a serious pane in the ass cheeks :(

Also, watch out for YSlow doing the same if it is set to Auto-Run obviously!

Comment: OMG. I spent like half an hour trying to figure that out. Then I decided to search the stackoverflow. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't have thought of disabling firebug.

Comment: if you want to keep firebug enabled you can try returning a View instead of redirect during debug mode:#if (DEBUG)
   return View("NewAction");
#else
   return RedirectToAction("NewAction", new { id= viewModel.ID });
#endif

Comment: Just noticed that Chrome 18.0.1025.168 does this as well...with or without developer tools open

Comment: Three years latter and I got caught by the same problem. Tore what little hair I have out for a couple of hours until I found this answer!

Answer (score 15):

Here's a basic checklist (copied from [here](http://blog.evereq.com/blog/index.php/2010/07/asp-net-mvc-controller-action-being-called-twice-issues/)):

1. Check that you don’t have any image or another elements in the View with an 
   empty `src` attribute (`<img src=”" />` for example) or have `src`
   attribute referencing something that no longer exists. You better
   check directly in the browser's “Page Source”, than in the View itself due to the
   possibility of some “dynamic” issues when the View is rendered. Once you
   find such empty element in the page's `HTML` source its usually trivial to
   find the same element in your View and fix the issue. This can also happen with `<link href="">`.
2. Check that you don’t have any `AJAX` calls referencing an empty `URL` (browsers will interpret such empty `URL` as the current page and will request the current page again making the `Controller` action execute few times).
3. You forgot to return `“false”` from the `JavaScript` click event handler for a link or button that makes an `AJAX` call. If you forget to `“return false”`, the browser simply interprets the default action of the link – regular, non `AJAX`, calling the same page again)
4. Sometimes Firebug and YSlow [ Firefox (FF) plugins ] can cause such issues. Just temporarily disable them in FF or test with a different browser.
5. Watch out for duplicate filters decorating your controller or action. (this was my problem)

Comment: I have seen this behavior. I had a grid with img src attribute getting set to # and the controller was getting for each image. Again this thing only happens in FF. What a sucking browser. I am having this issue again. Scratching my head to find the line in 1200 lines...

Comment: Thank you Leniel Macaferi, I spent a lot of time to understand that my case was <link href="">.

Comment: It worked after I removed the <link href="#" id="colour-scheme" rel="stylesheet"> from my layout page.

Comment: #1 for me. Under an HTML `<video>` tag I had `<source src="#">` for two different sources. The controller was loading 3 times. Once I removed both these `src="#"` tags the controller correctly loaded only once.

Comment: For me the problem was imgs with src="#", removing this attirbute solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution for this case..

I had exactly same problem, running and testing from **Chrome**. I couldn't debug it because the second call was coming from (external call). I have randomly tested it in **Firefox** and **Internet Explorer** where there was no double hit.

Whatever nasty thing it was, I have **deleted Chrome cache** (everything!!!) and problem has been resolved.

Hope it will help some of you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a controller action that generated an image, and I was only seeing it with Firefox. There is a really old bug that causes this, that I guess is still there.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=304574